Using a .ps1 script to open Anaconda Prompt and pass in multiple commands. Failing after opening the prompt
I am trying to use a powershell script to open anaconda prompt, activate an environment, move directory and launch a script. I've simplified the list of commands as it fails on the first one.
Here is the ps1 script:
# Path to the Anaconda Prompt shortcut
$anacondaPromptPath = "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Anaconda (anaconda3)\Anaconda Prompt.lnk"

# Commands to be executed in the Anaconda Prompt
$commands = @(
    "conda activate automation"
)

# Create a string of commands separated by '&'
$commandString = $commands -join " & "

# Start the Anaconda Prompt and execute the commands
Start-Process -FilePath $anacondaPromptPath -ArgumentList "/K $commandString"

It opens the anaconda prompt fine, but then when trying to execute the commandString I get this error message:

ArgumentError: activate does not accept more than one argument: ['C:\ProgramData\anaconda3', 'conda', 'automation']"

I've tried tinker with double-quoting but no luck so far.
